# How to display and control current value of a 2d slider

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, slider

Regarding the use of 2D sliders in `Manipulate`:  (1) How do you display the current value (x,y) that corresponds to the location of the slider point? (2) How can one enter a precise value for (x,y) to control the location of slider?

Comment: Use the option `Appearance -> "Labeled"`, e,g, `Slider2D[{0.5, 0.5}, Appearance -> "Labeled"]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nontrivial part of your question is (2) if interpreted as :

"How to use a 2D Slider and some 1D Sliders to manipulate the same object {x,y} ?"

Here is one way to do it :

```
Manipulate[WhatEverFunction[pt],
{{pt,{.5,.7}},{0,0},{1,1},TrackingFunction :> ((pt=#;x=#[[1]];y=#[[2]])&)},
{x,0,1,Manipulator,TrackingFunction :> ((x=#;pt[[1]]=#)&)},
{y,0,1,Manipulator,TrackingFunction :> ((y=#;pt[[2]]=#)&)}]
```

[image]

You can use either the 2D Silder or the 1D sliders to change pt={x,y}.

Note that you can open the 1D sliders (push the small button + on the right side) to access to a input field.